# Blazor | CSS not loading if razor file and project has the same name in Linux

Tags: .net, linux, razor, blazor

I am using dontnet version 5.0.408 and running dotnet in LINUX. In my Blazor app if I have the project folder and the razor file name as same and add the AdditionalAssemblies in the app.razor of main project file the CSS associated to the razor page does not load. Additionally no errors are thrown in the console as well.

BlazorApp
/app.razor
Dummy
/page
/Dummy. razor
/Dummy. razor.css
/Dummy. razor.cs

CSS loads if I rename the file to be different from the project name. I am not able to understand the issue. My thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, I just want to know if the issue would happen when you test the app in a windows environment?

Comment: I created this app in Windows and it worked as expected. But when I moved it to Linux it did not load the static razor files. When I renamed the files it worked. And when I reverted the names and tried running again it worked.